# Why doesn't compiler prompt double definition when using detection idiom?

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, void-t

Lets take something concrete:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename ... Ts>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_lt_comparable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_lt_comparable<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type {};                    

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool is_lt_comparable_v = is_lt_comparable<T>::value;

struct test{};

int main()
{
    #define error_message "detection doesn't work correctly"
    static_assert(is_lt_comparable_v<int>, error_message);
    static_assert(!is_lt_comparable_v<test>, error_message);
    static_assert(is_lt_comparable_v<std::vector<int>>, error_message);

}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LpTUANFRBFSaXfmI).

In the code above, why doesn't first and the last asserts trigger double definition of `is_lt_comparable`?

`void_t` with any arguments is still `void`. As such, the last unnamed parameter for the template is always `void`. IIRC type aliases are not considered distinct types, thus my intuition leads me to believe that I'm missing something.

**Specifically**, given a choice that both declaration are valid, and result in the same type, e.g. in the first one, `is_lt_comparable<int, void>`, how does it know which template to instantiate?

Comment: This might as well be named "Why detection idiom works", but I wasn't sure if it is a good title.

Comment: Do you understand that in this snippet the second appearance `template <typename T> struct is_lt_comparable` designates a *template specialization*?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, but why it is not treated the same as first appearance?

Comment: @Incomputable You might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858395/why-is-the-template-specialization-not-chosen/44858464#44858464 (not really a dupe though) Maybe it'll help.

Comment: The first one is not a specialization, it's the struct template itself. If a type is comparable, the specialization is preferred over the original struct because that's how they work. If it's not comparable, SFINAE discards the specialization and the original struct is used.

Comment: Are you asking how a specialization is different from a plain template? It has a pair of `<>` with some arguments after a (struct) name.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, no. I understand the case when it is not comparable. I'm not getting the case when it *is* comparable. It is still `is_lt_comparable<T, void>`, it is able to instantiate both. How does it figure out which one to instantiate? The first one?

Comment: A (most specialized) specialization is always used when possible. The original doesn't need to be discarded by SFINAE or anything.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, so it is about precedence? Like in function overload resolution?

Comment: I guess it's similar in a sense.

Comment: It seems that your question can be reduced to: `template <typename> struct S {static constexpr int x = 1;};` `template <> struct S<int> {static constexpr int x = 2;};` `std::cout << S<int>::x; // 2`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, exactly. Close as a dupe, I guess?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I can't find a proper dupe target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write: `is_lt_comparable<int>`. This is what happens.

1. The primary template is chosen, and the second template argument is inferred, because it's the default. So, you actually have `is_lt_comparable<int, void>`.
2. Now the template specializations are considered, to see if there is a match.
3. It finds the first (and only) specialization, and because it is a partial specialization, not a full one, it needs to instantiate it too, basically. So you get:

   ```
   is_lt_comparable<int, void_t<decltype(std::declval<int>() < std::declval<int>())>>
   ```

   Now, if the `<` expression is ill-formed, then the specialization is not considered, and the compiler fall backs to the primary template.
4. But if it is valid, then the partial specialization becomes: `is_lt_comparable<int, void>`. And that is an exact match from the template that we instantiated in 1), so the compiler chooses that one. Formally, this is known as the partial ordering rules.

If you are still confused, consider this:

```
template<typename> void foo() {}
template<> void foo<int>() {}
```

If I do `foo<int>()`, there also won't be a double definition error, like you said there'd be. The specialization is a better match than the primary, so the compiler doesn't even instantiate the primary template with `T = int` (it can't).

Comment: This was the explanation I was searching for. I would like my question to be closed as a dupe if possible, but it seems like there is no proper dupe target. Should I edit the question to better fit the answer?

Comment: @Incomputable Please don't. That would invalidate mine and the other answers

Answer (score 1):

A `static_assert` is a *declaration* and doesn't define any entities. See [cpprefrence article on Definitions and ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). There are only template instantiations in your code, but no definitions.

Answer (score 0):

> In the code above, why doesn't first and the last asserts trigger double definition of is_lt_comparable?

`is_lt_comparable` is not a type. It's the name of a template.

`is_lt_comparable_v<int>` results in expansion of `is_lt_comparable<int, void>`, which is a type.

`is_lt_comparable_v<test>` results in the expansion of `is_lt_comparable<test, void>`, which is a different type.

And once again, `is_lt_comparable<std::vector<int>, void>` is yet another distinct type.