# Combining void_t and enable_if?

Tags: c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if, void-t

In `C++17`, `void_t` allow to easily do SFINAE with `class`/`struct` templates:

```cpp
template <class T, class = void>
struct test {
    static constexpr auto text = "general case";
};

template <class T>
struct test<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>())>> {
    static constexpr auto text = "has begin iterator";
};
```

What's inside `void_t` is a type. My question is: how to do the same, when what's inside `void_t` is a type trait. Using `enable_if` works well:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct test<T, std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<T>>> {
    static constexpr auto text = "is a class";
};
```

Is there a shorter/more elegant way to write this, or "the right way" to do it, is really to combine `void_t` and `enable_if`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A important point of `std::void_t` is that is variadic

```
// ................VVV  <- is variadic
template <typename ...>
using void_t = void;
```

so permit the SFINAE works when you have to check a multiplicity of types and permit you a soft fail when only one of them fail.

In a case when you have to check only a value and you have to check it with `std::enable_if` (or a similar type trait) I don't see reason to use it together with `std::void_t`.

So, in your example, "the right way" (IMHO) is avoid the use of `std::void_t`

```
template <class T>
struct test<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<T>>
 { static constexpr auto text = "is a class"; };
```

Also in the case of the use of a single `decltype()` I prefer the old way (but I suppose it's a question of personal taste)

```
template <class T>
struct test<T, decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>(), void())>
 { static constexpr auto text = "has begin iterator"; };
```

Comment: No, we have to use this awesome new technique. In fact, it's so awesome we should use it as many times as we can: `std::void_t<std::void_t<std::void_t<std::void_t<std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<...>>>>>>` :)

Comment: @T.C. - do you mean that I'm obsolete with old `decltype()` way to declare an integer value :( - `decltype(decltype(decltype(decltype(decltype(std::enable_if_t<true>(), int{}){}){}){}){}) intVal;`

Answer (score 10):

You don't seem to understand why `std::void_t` is necessary. Let's fix that :)

In your first example, if you don't use `std::void_t`, then the partial specialization will never get chosen, because the `decltype` would evaluate to some type `T` that is not `void`, and so it won't be a match the partial specialization and would fall back to the general case. Now you can always change the default argument in the primary template if you know that your function will always return the same type, but that way is way more brittle to change. (You can have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858395/why-is-the-template-specialization-not-chosen/44858464#44858464) that I gave to another question which might help to understand this).

This is why `std::void_t` was introduced. `std::void_t` is just an identity type trait that is `void` no matter what. This means that in your first example, no matter what the `decltype` evaluates to, the second template parameter will be `void` and thus will match and the specialization will get chosen, if the `decltype` is well-formed.

`std::enable_if_t` is valid and is by default `void` if and only if the condition inside it evaluates to true. This means that `std::enable_if_t` *already* returns a `void` no matter what and thus you don't need `std::void_t` to "transform" it into a `void`, because it is already `void`.

Comment: If I "explained" something that doesn't make sense, please tell me. Sometimes I can't explain things very well, thanks :)