# Using decltype in partial template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

With the following template and specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct A {
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "primary" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, decltype(T().f())> {
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

used like this:

```
struct X {
    bool f() { return false; }
};

int main()
{
    A<X>()();
    return 0;
}
```

the primary template is resolved, when one would expect partial specialisation to be selected. However, when changed to:

```
template<typename T>
struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_object<decltype(T().f())>::value>::type> {
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

the specialization is chosen. Why isn't specialization chosen in the original example?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I don't think that's a duplicate.  That duplicate describes an ill-formed template parameter.  This question involves a well-formed specialization that simply doesn't specialize the test usage.

Comment: Waited to see a "reopen" vote or a rebuttal before casting my "reopen" vote...

Comment: @DrewDormann That wouldn't matter anyways, but that's not true. The duplicate mentions both, and asks about why the specialization is not chosen for `int`. Here, it's the same question: Why is the specialization not chosen even though the expression is valid for the given types.

Comment: For the record, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858395) was the claimed duplicate.  I will let the crowd decide, rather than try to be objective.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have instantiated:

```
A<X>
```

Which leverages a default template parameter to become:

```
A<X,void>
```

Your specialization, however, is:

```
template<typename T>
struct A<T, decltype(T().f())>
```

Which, for template parameter `X` becomes:

```
struct A<X, decltype(X().f())>
```

Which is:

```
struct A<X, bool>
```

So, your specialization is not the correct choice, because `A<X,bool>` does not specialize `A<X,void>`.

---

If you want your specialization to work for **all** well-formed instances of `T().f()`, you can use C++17's [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

`std::void_t` will evaluate to `void` for **any** well-formed template parameters passed to it.

```
template<typename T>
struct A<T, std::void_t<decltype(T().f())>> {
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems like it's worth mentioning how you can fix this with things before C++17, i.e. by adding `,void()` to the `decltype` call, like `decltype(T().f(), void())`