# SFINAE template specialization not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N, typename V = int> // works if typename V = void
struct T
{
    const static int size = 0;
};

template <size_t N>
struct T<N,typename std::enable_if<(N>10)>::type>
{
   const static int size = 1;
};

int main (){
    cout << T<9>::size << endl; // 0
    cout << T<19>::size << endl;// 0  WHY?
    cout << T<10>::size << endl; //0  
}
```

Not sure why the output is the way it is, why isn't the specialization getting picked up?

Comment: Int != void, and enable_if resolves to void when the arg is true. Change primary template to `typename V = void`

Comment: Seems like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858395/why-is-the-template-specialization-not-chosen/44858464

Comment: Since you already noticed that it only works with `V = void`, can you explain why you think `V = int` should work?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the second argument is always `int`, since it's the default value:

```
int main (){
    cout << T<9, int>::size << endl;
    cout << T<19, int>::size << endl;
    cout << T<10, int>::size << endl;
}
```

But the expression `typename std::enable_if<(N>10)>::type` won't ever yield an `int`, so your specialization won't be picked. The default type for `std::enable_if::type` is `void`.

It will work only if you're sending `void` in the second argument (of course you don't want that):

```
int main (){
    cout << T<9, void>::size << endl;
    cout << T<19, void>::size << endl;
    cout << T<10, void>::size << endl; 
}
```

To make it work like you want, you must either make the default argument to be `void`, or make your constraint to always yield an `int` type.

```
template <size_t N, typename V = void>
struct T
{
    const static int size = 0;
};
```

Or alternatively make your constrain yeild the type of your default argument:

```
typename std::enable_if<(N>10), int>::type
```

In fact, you could put any type and it wouldn't change a thing. As long as the two type matches:

```
// silly but works, the two types are the same.
template<size_t N, typename = decltype(std::cout)>
struct T { /* ... */ };

template <size_t N>
struct T<N, typename std::enable_if<(N>10), decltype(std::cout)>::type> { /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the template parameter with default argument in your primary template, when you write `T<19>::size`, what you're really writing is `T<19, int>::size`.

Now, there exist partial specializations for your template, thus, when figuring out which specialization a *simple-template-id* like `T<19>` refers to, the compiler will try to find a matching partial specialization. To do so, it will look for a match between the actual template arguments `19, int` and the template arguments given in your partial specialization

```
template <size_t N>
struct T<N, typename std::enable_if<(N>10)>::type>
{     // ^-------------- this here -------------^
    …
};
```

The first step is to figure out the arguments for the parameters of your partial specialization itself. In your case, the partial specialization has one parameter `template <size_t N>`. This parameter is deduced by comparing the parameterized type `T<N, typename std::enable_if<(N>10)>::type>` to the actual type `T<19, int>`. Deduction yields `19` as argument for parameter `N`. Substituting back into the specialization, we get

```
struct T<N, void>
```

as the deduced argument list for our specialization because `std::enable_if<true>::type` is `void`. The argument list `19, void` is not the same as `19, int`, therefore, the specialization is not a match and the primary template will be used.

So to make this work, you have to make sure that the type produced by your `std::enable_if` argument matches the default argument of the last parameter of the primary template, i.e., either change the default argument to be `void`

```
template <size_t N, typename = void>
struct T
{
    …
};
```

or make your `std::enable_if` produce `int` in the cases where you want the specialization to be used

```
template <size_t N>
struct T<N, std::enable_if_t<(N>10), int>>
{
    …
};
```